# Instruction and memory tracer for executing program on windows

Tags: x86, tracing

Anyone know any popular x86 tracer which can capture the instruction and memory change by a running program on windows?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by tracing? A debugger should be able to provide the runtime information you are interested in